# calling Invoke-Expression with Parameters in Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, command-line-arguments

I've written a powershell module in c# that has a bunch of cmdlets like

Add-VM

The cmdlets reach out to an API and pull data back.

but for the sake of uniformity with the ssh CLI of the product, i've written a function called newtask that accepts 'addvm' as an argument and $args.

for example

```
newtask addvm -id 12345
```

I then invoke Add-VM and pass $args as a string like so

```
Invoke-Expression Add-VM $argstr
```

The problem is that Add-VM throws an error that it cannot find a positional parameter that accepts argument System.Object[]

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'

While I could easily alias 'addvm' to 'Add-VM', i'm trying to maintain uniformity with the ssh CLI so that new users can quickly start utilizing this module.

I figured that sending a string like '-id 12345' would suffice but it's not. Does the pscmdlet expect to receive something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that error is from Invoke-Expression not Add-VM and you just need quotes around the argument: `Invoke-Expression "Add-VM $argstr"`.

Comment: As an aside, why would I not just use Add-VM directly? This way just seems to add more typing.

Comment: @mikez while i agree with you, this module is for a product and the current users of a product are used to a certain syntax like i mentioned in the question. In the case of 'addvm', Add-VM makes sense but Delete is not a powershell verb so i had to use remove-vm for 'deletevm'. I'm trying to keep it as close to the original ssh shell on the product so that the transition is seamless.

Comment: Thanks @mikez. The ""s helped and got the job done. my bad.

Comment: If you want to use invocation as an abstraction layer you may want to use `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { ... $args } -ArgumentList ...` rather than `Invoke-Expression "... $argstr"`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I don't think that will quite work. Better would be a splat with `@args`. This would let you pass more complicated objects. Currently since the command is stuffed into a string you wouldn't be able to pass in a more complex object. You'd probably have to use a `switch` then to invoke the command. I don't think you can do it with `Invoke-Command`/`Invoke-Expression`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error is from Invoke-Expression not Add-VM and you just need quotes around the argument:

```
Invoke-Expression "Add-VM $argstr"
```

This has the drawback of forcing all objects into string format. This might be acceptable for simple types like ints and strings but if you want to pass through a more complex object it won't work. An alternative would be to splat the arguments with `@args` but I don't think you can do this through Invoke-Expression or Invoke-Command. You need to directly call the cmdlet:

```
function newtask {
    params([string]$command)

    switch ($command) {
        "addvm" { Add-VM @args }
        "deletevm" { Remove-VM @args }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for posting. Another option, which i'm using, is an array and simply check to see if $command is an element in $cmdlist.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is a little old now, but I was having a similar issue and a co-worker showed me that escaping $argstr prevents the object from getting converted to a string.

```
Invoke-Expression "Add-VM `$argstr"
```