# Powershell Passing Object and String to invoke-expression

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pass an object and a string variable to "Get-ADUser" commandlet using Invoke-Expression.

The credentials are built like this:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pwd -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($uid, $secpasswd)
```

then a string is composed with additional parameters:

```
if ($dc)
{
    $newVar = " -server $dc"
}

if ($ou) 
{
    $newVar = $newvar + " -Serchbase $ou"
 }
```

and finally the following is executed

```
$AllADUsers = iex "Get-ADUser $newVar -Credential $($mycreds) -Filter * -Properties *"    | Where-Object {$_.info -NE 'Migrated'}
```

but it brings up the credential dialog and an error if i just click ok

*Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Credential'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:54
+ Get-ADUser  -server srv-v-hh001.bwg.corp -Credential System.Management.Automatio ...
+                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser*

I think this is because iex is parsing $mycreds as a string, is there a way to tell Powershell this is an object?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615658/calling-invoke-expression-with-parameters-in-powershell for an example of using `Invoke-Expression` with parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need `IEX` at all? Use hashtable to build parameters for `Get-ADUser` and then just [splat](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) it:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pwd -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($uid, $secpasswd)

$Splat = @{
    Credential = $mycreds
    Filter = '*'
    Properties = '*'
}

if ($dc)
{
    $Splat.Server = $dc
}

if ($ou) 
{
    $Splat.SearchBase = $ou
}

$AllADUsers = Get-ADUser @Splat | Where-Object {$_.info -NE 'Migrated'}
```

BTW, you have a typo in your `SearchBase` parameter name.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!